# Printing out JSON array returned

Tags: array, json, parse

I have the following JSON array:

```
[{"occurences":"1","post_title":"Test 1","ID":"16"},    
 {"occurences":"1","post_title":"Test 2","ID":"19"},
 {"occurences":"1","post_title":"\u543b\u60a8\u7684\u5c41\u80a1","ID":"21"}]
```

And I use this js to parse and print it:

```
success:function(data){
     $.each(data, function(i, post){
     content = '';
     content += '<li>' + post.post_title + '</li>';
   });

   $(content).appendTo("#search-results");

   }
```

But the display only showed "Undefined", and the Console showed no errors.

In case you ask, this is the HTML part:

```
<form id="search" action="">
<div class="toolbar">
    <h1>Search</h1>
    <a href="#" class="back">Back</a>
</div>
<ul class="rounded">
    <li><input type="text" name="search-text" placeholder="Search" id="search-text" /></li>
</ul>
<ul class="edgetoedge" id="search-results">
    <li class="sep">Results</li>                
</ul>
</form>
```

Any clue why? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({

                  url: 'http://mypath/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',

                  data:{
                       'action':'go_ajax',
                       'fn':'spw_autosuggest',  
                       'queryString': $.trim(inputString.val())
                       },  

                  dataType: 'JSON',

                  success:function(data){
                            // this part is what happens with the JSON data

                            //console.log(data);

                            var content = '';
                            var data = $.parseJSON(data);

                            $.each(data, function(i, post) {
                                content += '<li>' + post.post_title + '</li>';
                            });

                            $(content).appendTo("#search-results");
                    },

                    error: function(errorThrown){
                       alert('error');
                       console.log(errorThrown);
                    }

        });
```

Comment: @syslogic, thank you for taking the time. I paste in the above the entire snippet of Ajax I have used all along. While you've probably got a point on the "parseJSON" being useless, I got null errors when it was left out. I'm still pondering on the issue.

Comment: The puzzle solved. I have tested and tested. I found this: there is absolutely no need for parsing data passed by Ajax, except that there is a conflict between the client-side jQuery and the server-side jQuery versions!

Answer (score 0):

Setting the proper dataType for the request is an important detail not considered in the answer above (this causes jQuery to send a HTTP Accept header with the request - and it will be expecting JSON data in the success callback as well):

```
dataType: 'json',
success:function(json){
   var content = '';
   jQuery.each(json, function(i, v){
      content += '<li>' + v.post_title + '</li>';
   });
   /* like this the results won't cummulate */
   jQuery("#search-results").html(content);
}
```

And sending the proper HTTP header with the response was also not considered:

```
header("content-type: application/json; charset=utf8");
```

Internet Exploder doesn't like that header - but this is another story [(read more)](http://www.codefx.biz/2011/02/json-with-internet-explorer).

Answer (score -1):

1. Add `var json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);`
2. Define `content` by adding `var content`
3. Place `content = '';` **before** the each-loop

Like this:

```
function (data) {
    var content = '';
    var json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

    $.each(json, function(i, post) {
        content += '<li>' + post.post_title + '</li>';
    });

    $(content).appendTo("#search-results");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Have tried your suggestions, but the problem persisted.

Comment: Although the #2 must have been right.

Comment: Sorry, retried and got it work.

Comment: You got it right except that my ftp server was being down. Sorry and thanks!!!

Comment: Erm ... jQuery.parseJSON(data) is pretty useless - because variable "data" already should be a JS object in the callback of the jQuery.ajax function... this would only apply if it's a JSON-string. I rather assume you send out the JSON without or with wrong HTTP headers.

Comment: Sorry, had to down-vote because the answer was slightly misleading, partially incorrect. I guess it works like that - but the way it works isn't like it's meant to be (sending JSON as text/plain and then parsing it again makes no sense, waste of electricity).